# C#/C++ TCP/IP Server/Client receives wrong message

Tags: c#, c++, tcp

I am currently writing a Logging Framework and I want to send the logs from C++ to a C# Server.

The client successfully connects to the server, but the string I send from C++ to C# does not get there correctly.

Server Code (C#):

```
public void Receive()
    {
        try
        {
            mListener.Start();


            string data = null;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");

                TcpClient client = mListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                data = null;

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                byte[] bytes = new byte[client.SendBufferSize];

                int i;

                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                }

                client.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (SocketException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", exc);
        }
        finally
        {
            mListener.Stop();
        }

    }
```

The code is from the Microsoft Example for the TcpListener.

Client (C++):

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in server;
if (sock < 0)
{
    std::cout << "Error creating socket" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
else
{
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error while connecting" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Error Code: " << errno << std::endl;
        return false;

    }
    else
    {

        ssize_t toSend = send(sock, &logtext, sizeof(logtext), 0);
        if (toSend == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Error while sending" << std::endl;
            close(sock);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Sent : [" << logtext << "]" << std::endl;
            close(sock);
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

The output of the C++ programm is the following:
**Loglevel: Debug, Log: Hi there, I am a test!

Sent : [Hi there, I am a test!]

Program ended with exit code: 0**

But the C# Server only receives the following:
**Waiting for a connection...

Connected!

Received: y??_?

Waiting for a connection...**

Of course I am doing something wrong... But I don't know what it is... Can someone help me?

Best Regards
ShanBox

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't shown us the type of `logtext`...

Comment: Ah, you're right - sorry!

`std::string log = "Hi there, I am a test!";
logger->logDebug(log.c_str());`

So it is a constant char*

Comment: std::string is a compund object, you cannot send it! However, you can send the string data buffer it wrapps: `send(sock, logtext.c_str(), logtext.length(), 0);`

Comment: I was able to solve the problem - thanks for the clues to get me there ;-)